# Not getting SafetyNet Api Attestation Response

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, safetynet, safetynet-api

I got an issue with google safetynet api attestation response. Even if i supplied the safetynet client, nonce and the apikey to the "client.AttestAsync()" method it won't return SafetyNetApiAttestationResponse. What could possibly wrong with below code? How to get attestation response to check whether android device is run on emulator or rooted device in xamarin forms?

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    Instance = this;

    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    BackgroundAggregator.Init(this);
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    DependencyService.Register<ToastNotification>();
    ToastNotification.Init(this);

    Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

    micService = DependencyService.Resolve<IMicrophoneService>();

    if (GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this, 13000000) == ConnectionResult.Success)
    {
        SafetyNetClient client = Android.Gms.SafetyNet.SafetyNetClass.GetClient(this);
        byte[] nonce = Android.Gms.SafetyNet.Nonce.Generate();

        bool valid = Task.Run(() => RunSafetyNetCheck(client, nonce)).Result;

        if (!valid)
            LoadApplication(new App());
        else
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Failed response validation with Google!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Update Google Play services.!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}

private async Task<bool> RunSafetyNetCheck(SafetyNetClient client, byte[] nonce)
{
    bool valid = false;
    SafetyNetApiAttestationResponse r = await client.AttestAsync(nonce, apiKey);

    if (r != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.JwsResult))
    {
        attestationResponse = r;
        var decodedResult = r.DecodeJwsResult(nonce);

        string error = null;
        if (VerifyAttestResponse(decodedResult, nonce, out error))
        {
            valid = await attestationResponse.ValidateWithGoogle(apiKey);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Compatibility Failed: " + error, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Failed to Check Compatibility", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
    return valid;
}

private bool VerifyAttestResponse(string data, byte[] sentNonce, out string errorMessage)
{
    errorMessage = null;
    var json = JsonObject.Parse(data);

    var error = GetValue(json, "error");
    var nonce = GetValue(json, "nonce");
    var timestampMs = GetValue(json, "timestampMs");
    var apkPackageName = GetValue(json, "apkPackageName");
    var apkCertDigestSha256 = GetValue(json, "apkCertificateDigestSha256");
    var apkDigestSha256 = GetValue(json, "apkDigestSha256");
    var ctsProfileMatch = GetValue(json, "ctsProfileMatch") == "true";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
    {
        errorMessage = "Response Contained an Error: " + error;
        return false;
    }

    var sentNonceStr = Convert.ToBase64String(sentNonce);
    if (!nonce.Equals(sentNonceStr))
    {
        errorMessage = "Nonce's do no match";
        return false;
    }
    if (PackageName != apkPackageName)
    {
        errorMessage = "Package Names do not match";
        return false;
    }
    if (!ctsProfileMatch)
    {
        errorMessage = "CTS Profile was false";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private string GetValue(JsonValue json, string field)
{
    if (!json.ContainsKey(field))
        return string.Empty;

    return json[field].ToString().Trim('"');
}
```

Comment: You can try to integrate Dotfuscator to make a run check to detect whether the app is running on a rooted device or emulator , please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/may/security-detect-and-respond-to-rooted-android-devices-from-xamarin-apps#adding-a-root-check.

Comment: I want to use safetynet(google play sevice api) instead

Comment: Could it be a deadlock scenario? I notice you are calling `.Result` on the task you are starting and you are not adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on your awaited calls.

Comment: Could you perhaps just make OnCreate `async void` and `await` the `RunSafetyNetCheck` call. Additionally add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on your awaited calls in the `RunSafetyNetCheck` method.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I tried what you have mentioned above.But still not getting any response.What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made my own sample here and cannot reproduce the behavior you see. You can find the full code in the following repository: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Xamarin-SafetyNet

The relevant parts are in my Activity I do:

```cs
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...

    var attestation = await safetynetHelper.RequestAttestation();
    ctsProfileMatch.Text = $"{attestation.ctsProfileMatch}";
    basicIntegrity.Text = $"{attestation.basicIntegrity}";
}
```

Inside of my safetynet helper I do the following:

```cs
public async Task<(bool ctsProfileMatch, bool basicIntegrity)> RequestAttestation()
{
    SafetyNetClient client = SafetyNetClass.GetClient(context);
    var nonce = Nonce.Generate(24);

    try
    {
        var response = await client.AttestAsync(nonce, attestationApiKey).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var result = response.JwsResult;
        var validSignature = await VerifyAttestationOnline(result).ConfigureAwait(false);
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // handle errors here
    }

    return (false, false);
}
```

Notice *all* calls have `.ConfigureAwait(false)`. We don't need to switch contexts all the time.

This works fine and loads the attestation as expected.

Comment: Hi @Cheesebaron I am getting below exception when calling client.AttestAsync as you have mentioned 
"com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7: " Do you have any idea on this ? and i have the network connectivity as well.

Comment: Looking up the error code it says "NETWORK_ERROR": https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes#NETWORK_ERROR

Comment: Thanks for the response @Cheesebaron . I have below doubts. In your blog you have mentioned to enable “Android Device Verification” API in Google cloud console. But When I search I come to see only Play Integrity API now. Is that okay to create API key on Play Integrity API Service instead device verification API. 2. And as per android documentation , “The SafetyNet Attestation API is deprecated and so you can no longer request a new API key.”

Comment: 1. To use play integrity API , Do we need to 1.  create a service account in could console with key and permission 2. Link that project in google play developer console ? And Play integrity API key to be created in play console ? 
Could you clarify the above doubts ? I am writing a new sample application in Xamarin Android and want to test App attestation feature. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the blog post linked in the repo?

Comment: I created a sample following your blog post only. I also tried by cloning your githup project as well.But still getting the same excpetion as mentioned above. As per Android documentation "The SafetyNet Attestation API is deprecated and so you can no longer request a new API key." So I would need to use Play Integrity API and key configuring from play developer console. Did you use play developer console for this ?

Comment: It is in the Google Cloud Console, you just enable the API in there.